# .htaccess redirect to subdirectory of directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have searched and searched but for some reason can not get this to work how I need it to. I need to write a rule in htaccess that checks to see if the file exists and if it does not look in a subdirectory of the original directory. For example if the request is:

```
www.mysite.com/css/main.css
```

if the file main.css is not found I need to redirect to

```
www.mysite.com/css/src/main.css
```

I have tried this in my .htaccess in the /css/ directory

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^css/?([^/].+)?$ /css/src/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Seams to me that this should be a very easy task but can not seem to get this working. Also in regards to debugging htaccess how to I log what the rewrite rule is looking for? I have this in my VirtualHost file:

```
LogLevel trace4
```

but this does not show where the rewrite rule is trying to go... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't seem right. Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^css/([^/]+)$ /css/src/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

For your second part you need:

```
LogLevel trace4
RewriteLog "/val/logs/rewrite.log"
```

Comment: Thank you anubava, this helped a bunch

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out, the problem I was having was the redirect here is my .htaccess file in case anyone is having a similar problem:

In my css directory I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/].+)?$ src/$1 [L]
```